# HTML 5 video not playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, iframe

I have a simple form where a user can enter input a name and submit ,  when user enter the user name, automatically the video is played in iframe,  when user click submit, I want to open a new page which contain a video automatically the video should play when user click submit.

Here is what I have gone so far:

Form page HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Wideo iframe</title>
    <!-- Website Font style -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/form.css">

</head>

<body>

    <iframe id="videoframe" src="videoframe.html"></iframe>
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row main">
            <div class="main-login main-center">
                <h5>WYP: Formularz.</h5>
                <form id="formData" name="contact" role="form" method="post" action="thankspage.html" target="_blank">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Imie</label>
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" id="button" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">


                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

here is form.js

```
//form script

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).resize(resizeIframe);
            $(window).resize();

            //play a video when user enter aa name
            $("input#name").on("change", function () {
                document.getElementById('videoframe').contentWindow.postMessage( "event=fieldchanged&fieldtype=" + "name" + "&value=" + $("input#name").val(), "*");
            });

            // play a video when a user clicks submit button this is not working !!!!!!!
            $("#button").on("click", function(){
              document.getElementById('videoframe').contentWindow.postMessage(
                  JSON.stringify({
                    event: 'submitSlide()'
                  }), "*")

            })


        });

        function resizeIframe() {
            console.log($("iframe#videoframe").width()*576/1024 );
            $("iframe#videoframe").height( $("iframe#videoframe").width()*576/1024 );

        }
```

here is videogframe.js

```
   var autoplay = true;


   var movieName1 = "./videos/videoplayback.mp4"
   var movieThanks = "./videos/darasa.mp4"



   function resizeFunction() {
       $("#videowrapper").height($("#videowrapper").width() * 576 / 1024);

   }

   window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

   function receiveMessage(eventPosted) {

       var values = eventPosted.data.split("&");
       var event = values[0].split("=")[1];
       var fieldtype = values[1].split("=")[1];
       var value = values[2].split("=")[1];

       console.log(event, fieldtype, value);

       switch (event) {
           case "fieldchanged":

               switch (fieldtype) {

                       case "name":
                       openSlide("nameSlide", {
                           value: value
                       });

                       case  "submit":
                       openSlide("submitSlide", {
                           value: value,

                       });
                       break;

                   default:
                       break;
               }
               break;
           default:
               console.log("Event not supported");
               break;
       }

   }

   function openSlide(slideName, params) {
       switch (slideName) {
               case "nameSlide":
               openName(params);
               break;

               case "submitSlide":
               openSubmit(params);
               break;
       }

   }

   var params = null;

   function openName(_params) {
    playVideo(movieName1);
   }
   function  openSubmit(_params){
     playVideo(movieThanks);
   }


 // function top play video
   function playVideo(src) {

       $("#playervideo").attr("src", src);
       $("#playervideo")[0].muted = false;


       if (autoplay == true) {

           var playPromise = $("#playervideo")[0].play();

           if (playPromise !== undefined) {

               playPromise.then(function () {}).catch(function () {

                   if (autoplay == true) {
                       $("#video-unmute-button").addClass("show");
                       $("#playervideo")[0].muted = true;
                       var playPromise2 = $("#playervideo")[0].play();

                       playPromise2.then(function () {

                       }).catch(function () {
                           $("#video-start-button").addClass("show");


                           $("#video-start-button").on("click", function () {
                               $("#playervideo")[0].muted = false;
                               $("#playervideo")[0].play();
                               $("#video-start-button").removeClass("show");

                           });
                       });

                       console.log("pause force");
                   } else {

                   }
               });
           } else {}
       } else {

       }

   }
```

Here video frame html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wideo iframe</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="videowrapper">
        <video  id="playervideo" controls></video>
        <canvas id="videocanvas" width="1024" height="576"></canvas>
        <div id="testform"><input type="text"/></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="jslibs/howler.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/videoframe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Am using post messege for communication.

Everything works as expected except when I click submit , it just open new page without playing a video .

> > UPDATE: please any one does not understand what I want , down
> >
> > Here is repo for what I am trying to do : [Video frame](https://github.com/throne1986/videoframe)
>
> just clone the repo run the page named formpage.html, start filling
>   the form u will see automatically video plays, but when u click the
>   submit button just opnes the page but the video is not playing : Test
>   it your self

**UPDATE: to be more specific I want to use post message like this  by adding event listner**.

```
  // play a video after the user click submit button
            $("input#button").on("click", function () {
                document.getElementById('videoframe').contentWindow.postMessage( "event=fieldchanged&fieldtype=" + "submit" + "&value=" + $("input#button").val(), "*");
            });
```

Why my video is not playing? what am I doing wrong?  thanks.

Comment: Did you try to play video with muted attribute set to true?

Comment: hii nik I will try now, u can try urself there is repo link above its just simple html javascript page , just clone it and run formpage.html u can see  everything

Comment: Nik if you set mmuted to true , when u enter user name play video without sound , so that does not solve the issue?

Comment: Can you setup a demo? So we can help you debug it (create a fiddle or plunkr)

Comment: You won't get auto play of unmuted video. That's a browser vendor policy many of our clients can't understand and many user are so thankful for

Comment: @Red okay give me some minutes I am creating it

Comment: @red plunker does not allow me to save the files please just clone this repo here [repo](https://github.com/throne1986/videoframe)

Comment: :I am tried solving this issue damn , any one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually very simple, it's not working because you're putting the video tag inside the iframe tag in your `thankspage.html`, remove the iframe tag and add the muted flag and it should work.

So change this

```
<iframe id="videoframe" src="videoframe.html">
  <video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
    <source src="./video/janusz.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</iframe>
```

to this :

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay muted>
    <source src="./videos/janusz.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This will of course break your CSS, but you can easily manage to resize it accordingly afterwards by putting the video tag inside a div and manipulate the div.

As you can see here : https://jsfiddle.net/8xfq9urh/

Comment: Thanks islam, I want to play videos inside iframe because they will be used to another domain remove that video tag and add eventlistner to post message, check other video how I did it , I want the same but unfortunatelly I dont know how with submit button

Comment: I tried something like this : ` $("input#button").on("onlick", function () {
                document.getElementById('videoframe').contentWindow.postMessage( "event" + "button" + "&value=" + $("input#button").val(), "*");
            });`

Comment: @user9964622 my answer replies your current question, you didn't specify anything else in your original post. Can you please ask another question for any other questions you might have?